# KDB - import .csv on Mac from different path

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to import a .csv on a Mac and I can't seem to get the path right.

This works:
testtable: `` ("SS";enlist ",") 0:`testtable.csv ``

This doesn't work:
testtable: `` ("SS";enlist ",") 0:`/Users/ks/q/testtable.csv ``

Does anybody know the correct syntax to get the full path working?  My goal is to load the .csv from a shared Dropbox folder but I can't do that until I get the correct path syntax.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

kdb+ expects the file path as a symbolic file handle. The below link includes useful details.

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/11_IO/#1111-file-handles

In your case,

```
("SS";enlist ",") 0:hsym `$"/Users/ks/q/testtable.csv"
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...

Figured it out.  Can't believe how much time I spent on this...just need to add a second `:` after the `` ` ``

`` testtable: ("SS";enlist ",") 0:`:/Users/ks/q/testtable.csv ``

Answer (score 0):

The `key` function can come handy while debugging:

1) When used with a handle pointing to a folder, it will list all the contents of that directory :

```
q)key `:/Users/ks/q
testtable.csv
```

in case it is not the correct path, it will return an empty list

```
q)key `:/Users/ks/k
()
```

2) when used with a handle pointing to a file, it will return the file name

```
q)key `:/Users/ks/q/testtable.csv
`:/Users/ks/q/testtable.csv
```